# can setItemWidget add widget to the bottom of QListWidget?

Tags: pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I am using pyqt5 for a project and I am still learning it, I want to add notification popup to it and I find the following code on GitHub:[link](https://github.com/PyQt5/PyQt/blob/master/Demo/Notification.py), which is perfect but instead of every notification appears from the top and push older one to the bottom, I want to reverse it notification appear from the bottom then new ones push the old ones above.

I know that notificationwindo class inherits from QListWidget class and every type of notification creates an instance of a notificationwindo class if window isn't existing then create an object of QListWidgetItem at the end add both of NotificationItem and QListWidgetItem to the notificationwindo with setItemWidget.

I tried some to use additem instead of setItemWidget but I was missing the link between the widget and the item.